# Bootstrap Nav Bar - Text Layout

Tags: bootstrap-4, nav

I'm trying to set-up a navbar on a site I'm working on and I'm having a bit of an issue.

In the code below my navbar text is display on separate lines, which I only want it to do that when it's in the collapsed view and not normal view. Any ideas? I'm probably just being stupid here but any help is appreciated. (Also, any tips or anything about good practices or something I'm doing wrong, please say so I can fix it for the future.)

```css
* {

 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

html, body {
 
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

.container-fluid {

 padding: 0px !important;
}

#collapsedNavbar  {
 
 text-align: center;
}

#header {
 
 height: 100px;
 margin-top: 75px;
 text-align: center;
}

#content-container {
 
 
}

#content {

}

#art-work {
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
 
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Conner Murphy">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 viewport-fit=cover">
  
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index-style.css">
  
  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <title> </title>
 
 </head>
 
 <body>
 
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light justify-content-end">
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsedNavbar" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsedNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Art Work</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Graphics/Design</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Other</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  
  </nav>
 
  <div class="container-fluid" id="content-container">
  
   <div class="container" id="header">
    
    <div class="row">
    
     <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h1>Test Title</h1>
     </div>
    
    </div>
    
   </div>
   
   <div class="container-fluid" id="content">
   
    <div class="container" id="art-work">
    
     
    
    </div>
   
   </div>
  
  </div>
  
  <footer class="footer">
  
   <div class="container">
   
   </div>
  
  </footer>
 
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Solved. Never mind, I realised my own stupidity. Put all 3 links inside on list item.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping `nav-link` in `nave-item` wrap nav-item in `navbar-nav` See the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/#nav)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 0px !important;
}

#collapsedNavbar {
  text-align: center;
}

#header {
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}

#content-container {}

#content {}

#art-work {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Conner Murphy">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 viewport-fit=cover">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index-style.css">

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title> </title>

</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light justify-content-end">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsedNavbar" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsedNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Art Work</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Graphics/Design</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Other</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </nav>

  <div class="container-fluid" id="content-container">

    <div class="container" id="header">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <h1>Test Title</h1>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid" id="content">

      <div class="container" id="art-work">



      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <footer class="footer">

    <div class="container">

    </div>

  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```